# Transaction implementation with Enterprise Library

Tags: c#

I am using `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data` for database related activities in my application. I have written some code where I am executing a deletion as well as updating some records using two `ExecuteNonQuery`. I want to put these in a single transaction. How I can implement that using  `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data`?

What modification is required in the following code to use a transaction?

Code is as following:

```
int iUpdate = 0;
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(dbRegion);

try
{
    string sSQL = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE Number = 1 ";
    db.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, sSQL);

    string sqlCommand = "spInsertToTable";
    DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand);

    iUpdate = db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);        
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Also... I assume you're going to either (1) have some more logic in your `catch`, or (2) have some clean-up code in a `finally`... otherwise you really shouldn't be using a try/catch here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TransactionScope object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this.